# Framework7 Calendar open only after refresh html

Tags: calendar, html-framework-7

I am having trouble with openning calendar (Framework7) on mobile when testing.
It works fine on all browsers but not when using directly mobile phone.
On mobile (safari test for me), when the 'Select Date' is clicked nothing happens and no error on console. If I refresh the page and click another time, then it's working.

my-app.js :

```
> myApp.onPageInit('checkout', function (page) { var calendarDefault =
> myApp.calendar({
>     input: '#shipping_calendar',
>     multiple: true }); })
```

checkout.php :

```
<div class="contactform">
<h4 class="checkout_title">DATE DE LIVRAISON</h4><br>
Sélectionnez une ou plusieurs dates<br>

<input type="text" placeholder="Select range date for delivery" readonly id="shipping_calendar">
</div>
```

Hope someone can help
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this issue happen since you try to load calender var in pageInit, but this will not trigger all time...so that Try to remove calendar code from `myApp.onPageInit` and set it direct in you script:

```
var calendarDefault = myApp.calendar({input: '#shipping_calendar', multiple: true });}
```

Also you you can do this to make sure its open:

```
var $$ = Dom7;
$$('#shipping_calendar').on('click', function(){
    if(!calendarDefault.opened)
          calendarDefault.open();
});
```

Comment: Thank you Anees !

Comment: Welcome mate :)